# How do I locate the failure in a failure to convert varchar to int in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column of `varchar(50)` that I want to convert to `int` using this line of code:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table].[dbo].[example]
ALTER COLUMN XYZ int
```

I eyeballed the contents of column `XYZ` and they look like integers that never exceed 9999.

I'm familiar with the debugger in Visual Studio and know how to step through code.  However, when I try to use the SQL Server Mgmt. Studio debugger, I do not know how to zero in on and fix the field that throws this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'XYZ' to data type int.

The query runs for about 1 minute, seeming to work, but then the above error pops up.

Comment: See my answer and let me know what gets returned.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to determine which fields will not convert properly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM example 
WHERE xyz LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

The records return are the one that will not CAST properly when you ALTER your table.  Decimals stored in varchar fields will not cast to ints either.

Consider:

`select CAST('1.1' as int)` -- this returns an error.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, when I run this I get 2 rows returned, and the rows simply replicate the column headers.  This is confusing to me, as I don't know how to interpret this

Comment: What do you mean by replicate column headers?  The XYZ column has data as 'XYZ'?

Comment: Exactly.  Row 1, in XYZ column it says XYZ.  Row, in XYZ column, it says XYZ.

Comment: Then that's your problem :) -- Update those to some value -- either NULL or '' presumably.  You cannot convert the varchar value 'XYZ' to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You an use [`IsNumeric()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) to find the rows that do not have an `int` value in the column:

```
select *
from example
where isnumeric(xyz) <> 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60f16/3)

You can also, use a `CASE` statement:

```
select 
  case 
    when isnumeric(xyz) <> 1 
    then xyz end
from example
where isnumeric(xyz) <> 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b852/1)

If you want to find records that might contains a period so they are not `int` values, then you can use:

```
select  xyz
from example
where isnumeric(xyz) <> 1
  or charindex('.', xyz) <> 0
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b852/6). Once you identify these records, you can determine how to proceed with the `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: This yields all the rows in which column XYZ is simply empty, or at least appears to be.  If it's empty and I attempt to convert to int, is that what causes this failure to convert error?  How do I avoid this from happening?

Comment: @phan Is it an empty string or it is a blank space?

Comment: I can't tell the difference.  With my eyeballs I simply see an empty cell.  How can I tell the difference?

Comment: @phan Use `len(xyz)` is zero then is it empty if greater than zero than is has blank spaces

Comment: Ok, will do that now.  Ultimately, how do I take both of these situations and make it so that it doesn't throw an error in my conversions from varchar(50) to int?

Comment: @bluefeet -- see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8445 -- your above query returns decimals which won't convert when OP runs ALTER.  blanks and nulls will convert -- my guess is a value might have a decimal...

Comment: @sgeddes I included a version that will check for `.`.

Comment: @Bluefeet When I added where isnumeric(XYZ) <> 1 AND LEN(XYZ) = 0, I get 2 less results/rows than isnumeric(XYZ) <> 1.  This is weird because it seems somehow related to the 2 results that I get from running sgeddes' query.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to insure the value can be cast is to use a `Try_Cast/Try_Parse` function in SQL Server 2012 or a `Try Catch` pattern in earlier SQL server versions.

The `Isnumeric` function is of almost no value here because, as you can see, if you run the statement below it will return 1 (true) for the value shown...... and yet the value can not be cast or converted to any numeric data type.

Using the regular expression `"NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' "` to test your value will eliminate the issues with non-numeric characters in the string.  However, it will not guarantee that the value can be cast to a given data type. For example `"999999999"` is a valid integer yet it will cause an overflow error if you cast it to a `smallint`.

```
Ex1
Select Isnumeric('$123,456.00')
--Select Cast( '$123,456.00' as int)
--Select Cast( '$123,456.00' as numeric(6,2))
--Select Cast( '$123,456.00' as decimal(6,2))
--Select Convert(int, '$123,456.00')
--Select Convert(numeric(6,2), '$123,456.00')
Select Convert(decimal(6,2), '$123,456.00')
```