# sql server - check to see if cast is possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following code to cast nvarchar to integer:

```
     cast(@value as int)
```

However I have no control of the parameter @value, hence the code might fail. Is there anyway to check if a cast is possible before doing a cast?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, in SQL Server 2012 you could use the new [TRY_CAST()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea3a16de-995b-415c-b5f0-9355cf7bb401), but with SQL Server 2008, you should be able to use [ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), and then include handling for values that do not pass that test.

Comment: ISNumeric('a1a') returns 1, however you can never cast('a1a' as float)

Comment: I believe you meant SQL Server 2014: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx

Comment: It existed in both. There's a dropdown to change versions - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 14):

I've recently answered a question about this and using `ISNUMERIC` to `CAST` to an `INT` won't work by itself.  Reason being, `ISNUMERIC` returns true for non integer numbers (1.5) for example.

Here was a recent answer on the subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692165/1073631

Consider adding an additional check using CHARINDEX with ISNUMERIC, or what I prefer, use a Regular Expression to validate the data.

And here is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8509) demonstrating the problem with using ISNUMERIC on it's own.  And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8522) using a regular expression instead that works.

```
DECLARE @Test nvarchar(10)
SET @Test = '1.5'
--Works
SELECT CASE WHEN @Test NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CAST(@Test as int) ELSE 0 END 
-- Produces Error
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@Test) = 1 THEN CAST(@Test as int) ELSE 0 END
```

Good luck.

Comment: +1 . . . The first is right.  Your answer should be a bit clearer that the second is wrong (I have to scroll to see the "Produces Error").

Comment: You should also guard against overflows (and optionally permit negative integers): http://stackoverflow.com/a/24250511/1149773

Answer (score 10):

I generally use the following, it seems to cover all the situations.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = ISNUMERIC(@value + '.0') THEN CAST(@value as int) ELSE 0 END
```

It takes advantage of the fact that "ISNUMERIC" will not allow two periods. The "TRY_CAST" in SQL Server 2012+ is a much better solution though.

Comment: Best answer by far for pre-2012 DBs.

Answer (score 2):

The proper test is:

```
select (case when isnumeric(val) = 1 and val not like '%e%' and val not like '%.%'
             then cast(val as int)
        end)
```

The function `isnumeric()` returns 1 for anything that looks like a float, so you have to be careful.

You can also use what I consider to be a peculiarity of SQL Server.  You can cast the floating value 1.23 to an int, but you cannot cast the string value.  So, the following also works:

```
select (case when isnumeric(val) = 1
             then cast(cast(val as float) as int)
        end)
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. `isnumeric('+') == 1`. `isnumeric('-') == 1`.  `isnumeric` is a horrible implementation, and their answer leaves you open to multiple edge cases where a `cast` to `int` will fail despite your check.

Comment: @mattmc3  . . Did you notice that the OP accepted essentially this answer.  In addition, the conversion to `float` fixes many of those problems (although not with overflow).

Comment: The accepted answer gets the TRY_CAST part right for SQL 2012+. To use ISNUMERIC, you have to do a whole lot of gymnastics to handle edge cases. For example, plug '+' or '-' in as values of "val". The cast to `float` will bomb spectacularly. (^^ not my downvote BTW - I prefer comments to rep damage). This answer gives a way to use `ISNUMERIC` that actually handles edge cases and ensures that you have a proper `TRY_CAST` alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522056/how-to-determine-the-field-value-which-can-not-convert-to-decimal-float-int-i

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can do something like this:

```
declare @value as nvarchar(10) = 'A';

begin try
    select cast(@value as int);
end try
begin catch
-- do something
end catch
```

Comment: I like this approach but we can't do this inside of a SELECT statement, can we?

Comment: I have looked into this & tested it.  It doesn't meet my needs.  This only prints certain error info.      ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;   but, not my own error message that will identify the record.

Answer (score 0):

Use a procedure with a TRY CATCH block to suppress errors

i.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_try_cast
 @type nvarchar(MAX),
 @value nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @sql        varchar(MAX)
        DECLARE @out_table  TABLE(value varchar(MAX))

        SET @sql = 'SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(max), CAST(''' + @value + ''' AS ' + @type + '))'

        INSERT  @out_table
        EXECUTE (@sql)

        IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM @out_table WHERE value = @value)
            RETURN 1

        RETURN 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RETURN 0
    END CATCH

END

GO
```

Now you can call that with the passed string and desired type and the proc returns 1 for success and 0 for failure

```
DECLARE @ret int

-- This returns 0 - Fail
EXEC @ret = p_try_cast 'integer', '1.5'

-- This returns 1 - Success
EXEC @ret = p_try_cast 'integer', '1.5'

-- This returns 0 - Fail
EXEC @ret = p_try_cast 'char(4)', 'HELLO'

-- This returns 1 - Success
EXEC @ret = p_try_cast 'char(4)', 'HELL'
```