# Combined Where Clause in Mysql PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 table called `Classifieds` and `Classifieds_meta` below is the screenshot of classifieds_meta table

[CLICK TO SEE THE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaklL.jpg)

im writing a search filter function with muliple where clause like

```
SELECT *,classifieds.id as id 
FROM classifieds,classifieds_meta 
WHERE (category=2 OR category=3 OR category=4 OR category=5) 
AND ((meta_key='vehicle_make' and meta_value=3 OR meta_key='vehicle_make' and meta_value=4)
AND meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=9 OR meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=10 OR meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=11 ) 
AND classifieds.id=classifieds_meta.classifieds_id 
GROUP BY classifieds.id
```

But the above sql statement IGNORES `vehicle_make`, `meta_value` and `meta_key` field condition, and displays incorrect result, what i want to achieve exactly is i want to get vehicles where category is in (2,3,4 or 5) and meta_key is vehicle_make and meta_value is 3 or 4 and meta_key is vehicle_mileage and meta_value is 9,10 or 11.

can someone please help me to form better SQL statement to get right result

Comment: A screen dump doesn't allow for easy setup of a test case. Could you add some sample data and a desired result as text directly to your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/24123489/1741542 The database design seems similar `meta_key/value` vs `propertyname/value`. `meta_key` can't be `vehicle_make` *and* `vehicle_mileage` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `having` clause instead of a `where`.  You are trying to look for conditions across multiple rows:

```
SELECT *, c.id as id 
FROM classifieds c join
     classifieds_meta  cm
     on c.id = cm.classifieds_id 
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING sum(meta_key = 'vehicle_make' and meta_value in (3, 4)) > 0 and
       sum(meta_key = 'vehicle_mileage' and meta_value in (9, 10, 11)) > 0 and
       sum(category in (2, 3, 4, 5)) > 0
```

The `> 0` is saying that at least one row matches each condition.

Note that I also fixed the join to be use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but where is the condition for meta_key = 'vehicle_make' and meta_value in (2,3)? anyways your sql returns empty results

Comment: Thanks alot, but still your sql statement returns empty set even if there is rows matching the condition

Comment: Are you looking for all conditions being true or for any of them?  The above returns `id`s where all are true.  If you want any to be true, change the `AND` to `OR`.

Comment: When looking at the image, I suspect `meta_value` is of type char and some of the values are CSV.

Comment: @OlafDietsche . . . That is a good point, but MySQL should handle the comparisons correctly, unless there are unusual characters in the value.  Using bare integers is how the OP originally framed the query;.

Comment: Yes, ur answer actually works, but i dint understand why did u use sum()

Comment: `sum()` is counting the number of rows that match each condition.  The `> 0` is checking that there is at least one row for each `id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL does the comparison, but when you have `9,10,11` as value, the clause `meta_value in (10, 11)` won't match anything.

Comment: @OlafDietsche . . . Very true.  The screen shot only has a comma-delimited list for something called "property_features", which is not used in this logic.  Because all the other key names are singular, I don't expect that they would have multiple values.  If they can, I encourage the OP to ask *another* question.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff... I have multiple values in other meta_key like "vehicle_make", but its not there in the above screenshot but i have logic in the sql query

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for vehicles where category is 2,3,4 or 5 and (meta_key is vehicle_make and (meta_value is 3 or 4)) or (meta_key is vehicle_mileage and (meta_value is 9,10 or 11)).

In this case the query should be:

```
SELECT *,classifieds.id as id
FROM classifieds,classifieds_meta 
WHERE (category=2 OR category=3 OR category=4 OR category=5) 
AND  ((meta_key='vehicle_make' AND ( meta_value=2 OR meta_value=4)) OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' AND (meta_value=9 OR meta_value=10 OR meta_value=11)))
```

Use parenthesis to make your statement understandable and finally use the same parenthesis in your SQL query.

EDIT:

If you want to use IN the query would be:

```
SELECT *,classifieds.id as id
FROM classifieds,classifieds_meta 
WHERE category IN (2, 3, 4, 5) 
AND  ((meta_key='vehicle_make' AND  meta_value IN (2,4)) OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' AND meta_value IN (9, 10, 11)))
```

Comment: i want to fullfill both the condition vehicle_make and vehicle_mileage but you have used OR condition, if i replace it with AND it returns empty result even though i have rows matching both the condition

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what you have (excluding table connection and category filter):

```
((meta_key='vehicle_make' and meta_value IN (3,4)) AND meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=9)
    OR 
(meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value IN (10, 11))
```

Therefore the `vehicle_make` portion is impossible due to meta_value NEVER being both (3 OR 4) AND 9.

I think what you're going for is:

```
(meta_key='vehicle_make' and meta_value IN (3,4))
    OR 
(meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value IN (9, 10, 11))
```

All together now:

```
WHERE classifieds.id=classifieds_meta.classifieds_id AND category IN (2, 3, 4, 5)
AND (
    (meta_key='vehicle_make' and meta_value IN (3,4))
        OR 
    (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value IN (9, 10, 11))
)
```

The takeaway from this is operator precedence. AND pairs get evaluated before OR.

Comment: Oops left out some parens. :S Updated.

Comment: Now its working like charm, thanks alot bro... now if i want to add another condition called meta_key=vehicle_year and meta_value=2010, i just need to add     OR 
    (meta_key='vehicle_year' and meta_value IN (2010) after     OR 
    (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value IN (9, 10, 11)) right?